# Task-list manager app in PHP doesn't show the list of tasks

Tags: php

I am working on a task list manager for my class that I am in. I have to include sessions and I need to push each task into an array and be able to delete it from the array.

I think I am doing it correctly,but when I run the program, the task list shows up as empty. I think I may not be adding the tasks to the task-list array correctly, and I really would like a fresh set of eyes to take a look, because maybe you will see what I haven't.

#### index.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['tasklist'])) {
$task_list = $_POST['tasklist'];
} else {
$task_list = array();
}

// put the array in a session variable
$_SESSION['tasks']=$task_list;
$_SESSION['errors']=$errors;

//start the session to last one year
$lifetime = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;     // 1 year in seconds
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $lifetime);
//session_set_cookie_params($lifetime, '/');
session_start();

$errors = array();

switch( $_POST['action'] ) {
    case 'add':
    $new_task = $_POST['newtask'];
    if (empty($new_task)) {
        $_SESSION['errors'] = 'The new task cannot be empty.';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['tasks'] = $new_task;
    }
    break;
case 'delete':
    $task_index = $_POST['taskid'];
    unset($task_list[$task_index]);
    $_SESSION['tasks'] = array_values($_SESSION['tasks']);
    break;
}



include('task_list.php');
?>
```

#### task_list.php

```
   <?php
   session_start(); // Access the current session.

?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="header">
    <h1>Task List Manager</h1>
</div>
<div id="main">

<!-- part 1: the errors -->
<?php if (count($_SESSION['errors']) > 0) : ?>
<h2>Errors</h2>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $error) : ?>
        <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- part 2: the tasks -->
<h2>Tasks</h2>
<?php if (count($_SESSION['tasks']) == 0) : ?>
    <p>There are no tasks in the task list.</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($_SESSION['tasks'] as $id => $task) : ?>
        <li><?php echo $id + 1 . '. ' . $task; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<br />

<!-- part 3: the add form -->
<h2>Add Task</h2>
<form action="." method="post" >
    <?php foreach($_SESSION['tasks'] as $task) :
      array_push($_SESSION['tasks'],$task);
     endforeach; ?>
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add"/> -->
    <label>Task:</label>
    <input type="text" name="<?php $_SESSION['tasks'] ?>" id="newtask" value="<?php     echo $task; ?>" /> <br />
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Task"/>
</form>
<br />


<!-- part 4: the delete form -->
<?php if (count($_SESSION['tasks']) > 0) : ?>
<h2>Delete Task</h2>
<form action="." method="post" >
    <?php foreach($_SESSION['tasks'] as $task) :
      $_SESSION['tasks']=array_diff($_SESSION['tasks'],$task);
     endforeach; ?>
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete"/> -->
    <label>Task:</label>
    <select name="taskid">
        <?php foreach($_SESSION['tasks'] as $id => $task) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <?php echo $task; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete Task"/>
</form>
<?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- end main -->
</div><!-- end page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `session_start()` before any interaction with the session. So if the files are accessed separately then you need it in both. If `task_list.php` is only included in `index.php` then just move it to the top of `index.php`. Additionally, in your logic for the `add` action you dont have your syntax right to add a task to `$_SESSION['tasks']` array, instead you are overwriting it with whatever is in `$new_task`.

Comment: Did oyu change the code in your OP? `$task` is an instance variable in the loop so the only way it would be undefiend is if `$_SESSION['tasks']` is undefined/not an array or an empty array. However if it was the former you would get a php error.

Comment: i did change the code in my other problem. now i have all of the errors gone, but the adding of a variable in the task_list.php code does not ever refer back to the action function in the index.php file and i cant figure out how to get it to do that.

Comment: in this case id just use a query string so `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?action=add' ?>">` Then you would use `$_GET['action']` to retrieve the intended action.

Answer (score 0):

This is from Murach's PHP book. The book becomes bunk after like the 10th chapter. No valid explanations or examples and questions that assume you already know PHP because it doesnt teach you what you need to know.